# 3D рисунок из массива

Tags: python, python-2.x, numpy, matplotlib

Как можно будет сделать 3д рисунок по массиву? сейчас объясню. в моем случае массив это набор высот, т.е координата Z, при этом я знаю координаты 7251750.0, 250.0, 0.0, 5107000.0, 0.0, -250.0 верхний левый угол сетки и шаг с которым происходит движение по этой сетке, ее размер 998 x 963. можете объяснить на примере простого массива например:

```
[4,8,12,1
 3,9,11,3
 5,10,10,5
 2,15,7,4]
```

координаты для угла и шаг можете взять на свое усмотрение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
z = [
   [4,8,12,1],
   [3,9,11,3],
   [5,10,10,5],
   [2,15,7,4]
]

x = np.outer(np.linspace(0, len(z), len(z[0])), np.ones(len(z[0])))
y = x.copy().T # transpose
z = np.array(z)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_title('Surface plot')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете помочь у меня вот такая ошибка происходит:ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape, можно ли будет с вами связать по почте? чтобы отправить свой файл и вы могли взглянуть?

Comment: ошибка на этом коде?

Comment: скорее это связано с тем что массив я задаю не сам, а беру из файла

Comment: посмотрите его структуру, возможно там не список списков, а как у вас в примере просто список. Это не трудно преобразовать в двумерный

Comment: А может произойти эта ошибка из-за большого количества значений? просто их там коло 1 миллиона

Comment: Именно эта - нет

Comment: в моем случае массив имеет выглядит так                                                           `[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]`                                                                                                   
 разве это не список в списке?

Comment: да, правильно, долдно работать

Comment: можно тебе на почту файл отправить с кодом чтобы ты посмотрел?

Comment: Катаюсь на великах до ночи. Приеду, напишу